# the use of would in the sentence

Tags: modal-verbs

what is the difference between this two sentences " would you like to be a farmer ?" and "Do you like to be a farmer?" I know would is about specific time but there is no time in the sentence

Comment: Always make sure that the sentences are grammatically correct and properly punctuated before posting your questions.

Comment: Have you seen ell.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

‘Would you like to be a farmer?’ asks a hypothetical question. The person being questioned is not a farmer, but the speaker wants to know if it is an occupation that appeals to the person addressed.

'Do you like to be a farmer?’ is ungrammatical. In such a question what is required is not the infinitive ‘to be’, but the ‘-ing’ form: ‘Do you like being a farmer?’ In that situation, the person addressed is already a farmer, and the speaker wants to know if the occupation is to the addressee’s liking.

Answer (score 1):

[Would like](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/would+like) is an idiom used to express desire.

Comment: -1 That doesn't explain "the difference" as requested.